# Show/hide div with different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the user clicks on one of the images in the carousel a `position: absolute;` div should appear. The div contains two different images and a form based on the picture initially clicked and has a submit button. **How can I make a show/hide that displays different content for each image?**

Here's the code of one of the carousels (there are 4 on the website and the script should work with all four of them).

```
<div id="slider1">
    <a class="buttons prev" href="#">&#60;</a>
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-01.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-02.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-03.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-04.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-05.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/etichete/etichete vinuri pe desene 20-30-06.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="buttons next" href="#">&#62;</a>
</div>
```

The only solution that I have in my mind is to create 30 (that's the number of images) show/hide divs... so much for DRY I guess.

Comment: _two different images and a form based_ where do these images come from? Where is the div?

Comment: It's a div with the class ".show" containing two <img src=""> tags and a couple of inputs. Haven't posted it because currently it's a code spaghetti full of inline styling.

Comment: You mean 2 img tags with empty src? what would you pupulate them with since when you click on an image in the carousel you get only one img?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `data-something` attribute to the carousel images and load the content from a partial view via AJAX.

But this way you'll need to add conditions in that partial and show/hide content depending on that `data-something` (probably an Id).